# How to turn pandas table values into a specific json format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

For example, let's look at the following PANDAS table:
[sample_pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHynv.png)

Question: How can I create a json file that returns this:

```
{"data": 
[ 
[a1, a2, a3], 
[b1, b2, b3],
[c1, c2, c3]
]
}
```

I know in pandas, you can get each entry as

```
list(list(df.values)[i])
```

Please help!

Comment: have you tried this library https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code

```
import pandas
import json

df = pandas.DataFrame([['a1', 'a2','a3'], ['b1', 'b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3']],
                  index=['row 1', 'row 2','row 3'],
                  columns=['col 1', 'col 2','col 3'])

df.to_json(r'1Export_DataFrame.json',orient='values')


with open('1Export_DataFrame.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)


test_dict = {"data": data
}

with open('test.json', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(test_dict, json_file)
```

open the test.json file to get expected output as per your question requirement

[image: output]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) post, you can:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('your input')
your_json = df.to_json(orient='split')
```